# Leaning ladder problem: minimum angle and frictionless floor

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtpE5synod8) shows how to calculate the minimum angle for a leaning ladder considering static friction on the floor and a perfectly frictionless wall.

I have 2 questions:

1. If the wall had friction, would that influence the minimum angle?
2. Could the ladder stay in equilibrium using only the **friction on the wall** (unlimited friction, for example), if the **floor was perfectly frictionless**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the wall had friction, would that influence the minimum angle?

Yes, of course. The friction would provide an upward force, counteracting any tendency for the ladder to slip.

> Could the ladder stay in equilibrium using only the friction on the
> wall (unlimited friction, for example), if the floor was perfectly
> frictionless?

Comment: The attachment example is flawed: no matter how high the coefficient of friction, the normal force must be non-zero for any friction to exist, and any non-zero normal force would prevent the system from being in equilibrium.

Answer (score 1):

As to 2: no, this is not possible. The wall would exert a horizontal normal force on the ladder, and there would be no force to counter it. The ladder would be pushed away from the wall and start to slip.

Comment: True. Interesting, although maybe if it was attached to a sort of **hinge or horizontal surface** at the wall there could be an **upwards** normal force and this setup could work, right?

Comment: Sure, though for a hinge we wouldn't call it a normal force but a reaction force. And if it was "hooked" over a horizontal surface as you say, you could have a stabilizing friction force in the horizontal direction.